# spritecollide and killing sprites

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pygame

I have two sprite groups, `ship_list` has 20 ship sprites, and `all_sprites` has those 20 sprites, plus the player sprite. In the main loop, when a collision is detected between the player and anything in `ships_list`, I understand that the ship sprite that collided with player is removed from `ships_list`. When I run the program, all sprites appear and by moving the player into a ship sprite it vanishes. All well and good, except.. I don't understand why they are vanishing. The reason being that though I know the ships are removed from `ships_list` after a collision, It is the `all_sprites` list that is actually being redrawn each frame, and I haven't explicitly removed anything from it at any point, so is it the case that the collision is also removing the ship sprite from `all_sprites`?

```
ship_list = pygame.sprite.Group() # just ship sprites
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group() # ship sprites + player sprite

while not done:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT or score == 20:
            done = True

    screen.fill(BLACK)

    pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    player.rect.x = pos[0]
    player.rect.y = pos[1]

    **# is this line removing sprites from all_sprites??**
    ships_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, ship_list, True) # detect collisions
    for ship in ships_hit_list:
        score += 1
        print score

    all_sprites.draw(screen) # seems to lose sprites when ships_list does..
    ship_list.update() # updating the position

    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(24)

# properly quit
pygame.quit()
```

From https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollide

> ```
> pygame.sprite.spritecollide()
> ```
>
> Find sprites in a group that intersect another sprite.
>
> ```
> spritecollide(sprite, group, dokill, collided = None) -> Sprite_list
> ```
>
> Return a list containing all Sprites in a Group that intersect with
>   another Sprite. Intersection is determined by comparing the
>   Sprite.rect attribute of each Sprite.
>
> **The dokill argument is a bool. If set to True, all Sprites that
>   collide will be removed from the Group.** (It doesn't mention it removing it from any other group..)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at what is shown when a sprite is printed, you will see that it shows in how many groups the sprite exists.

A Sprite has a method called `kill`:

> remove the Sprite from all Groups
>
> kill() -> None
>
> The Sprite is removed from all the Groups that contain it. This won’t
>   change anything about the state of the Sprite. It is possible to
>   continue to use the Sprite after this method has been called,
>   including adding it to Groups.

It seems that what `sprite_collide` does, it just calls `kill()` on the sprite if a collision has taken place.

Comment: This would certainly explain what's going on, and it would also make sense of why that flag is called dokill.. Thanks